# Extracting the n-th elements from a list of named tuples in pandas Python?

Tags: python, list, pandas, tuples

I am trying to extract the n-th element from a list of named tuples stored in a df looking like this:

```
df['text'] = [Tag(word='Come', pos='adj', lemma='Come'), Tag(word='on', pos='nounpl', lemma='on'), Tag(word='Feyenoord', pos='adj', lemma='Feyenoord')]
```

I am trying to extract only elements that contain the pos information from each tuple. This is the outcome that I would like to achieve:

```
df['text'] = ['adj', 'nounpl', 'adj']
```

This is what I have tried this far:

```
d =[]     
count = 0
while count < df['text'].size:
    d.append([item[1] for item in df['text'][count]])
    count += 1
dfpos = pd.DataFrame({'text':d})
df['text']= pd.DataFrame({'text':d})

df['text']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

And this is the error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

What am I missing?

Solution: It seems that the easiest solution is to turn the tuples into a list. I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

```
d =[]
count = 0
while count < df['text'].size:
    temp=([list(item[1:-1]) for item in df['text'][count]])
    d.append(sum(temp, []))
    count += 1

df['text']= pd.DataFrame({'text':d})

df['text2']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Comment: What is `Tag`?.

Comment: Is Tag a class or a named tuple? what is it? How to do end up with those? Nltk?

Comment: Tag is a named tuple that I get using the treetaggerwrapper.

Comment: Can you say the output of `df['text'].apply(lambda x : x[1] if len(x) > 1 else None).values`

Comment: This also returns tuple index our of range error

Comment: Check out my solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your approach looks better, but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try indexing using apply if Tag is your named tuple i.e

Data Preparation :

```
from collections import namedtuple
Tag = namedtuple('Tag', 'word pos lemma')
li = [Tag(word='Come', pos='adj', lemma='Come'), Tag(word='on', pos='nounpl', lemma='on'), Tag(word='Feyenoord', pos='adj', lemma='Feyenoord')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':li})
```

For attribute based selection use `.` in apply since its a named tuple i.e

```
df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x : x.pos)
```

If you need an index based selection then use

```
df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x : x[1] if len(x)>1 else np.nan)
```

Output `df['new']`

```
0       adj
1    nounpl
2       adj
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Another solution is use `str[1]` for select value in `namedtuple`:

```
df['text1'] = df['text'].str[1]
print (df)
                          text   text1
0            (Come, adj, Come)     adj
1             (on, nounpl, on)  nounpl
2  (Feyenoord, adj, Feyenoord)     adj
```